# My update_attribute does not issue an UPDATE query, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model that does not update anything. I've been searching all over to see if there is a deeper log that could point me to the problem but with no success.

My simple code here does not issue an UPDATE query in my 'dev' log (it should when 'update_attribute' is called). Nothing is being updated:

```
task sandbox: :environment do

  Rails.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

  reminder = Reminder.create(ended: true)
  reminder.update_attribute(:ended, false)
end
```

I tried with another model I have an the 'update_attribute' does issue an 'UPDATE' query.

Is there anyway to debug this sort of thing? After hours of trying stuff I don't have the slightest idea of what is going on.

Comment: I believe the syntax for the update should be `:ended => false` or `ended: false` ...

Comment: Have you checked for failing validations?

Comment: I tried "reminder.update_attributes!(:ended => false)" to raise an exception but I still don't have anything...

Comment: This is when you get angry... I had 'def update' on the model an it was empty. Erased it and all is working fine.